# Can't send response after executed function NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I created function which we can see below :

```
    Board.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result) {
      if (err) res.send(err);

      replace(result)
        .then((result) => {
          res.send(result);
        })

    })
  })


function replace(result)  { 
  result.forEach((element, key) => {
    User.find({ _id: element.boardcards.members })
      .then((users) => {
        element.boardcards.members = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          element.boardcards.members.push(users[i].firstName + ' ' + users[i].surname);
        }
        console.log(element.boardcards.members)
      })
  }) 
  return result; 
}
```

When i run project I have error :

> TypeError: replace(...).then is not a function

I want after executed function replace send modified result to browser. , Could someone tell me what I am make wrong.

Comment: well... i mean... `return result;` result obviously isn't a promise. It's whatever you passed to it. array.forEach doesn't alter it.

Comment: Hey Kevin thanks for answer, could u tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make replace return a promise if you want to use it that way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Likely since you want to do multiple queries you will use Promise.all.

Comment: I want make one response, after replace arrays, I want to respond variable nothing more, seriously i should use promise all for that?

Comment: If you are using replace.then(), your replace has to return a Promise in your code example you are calling User.find multiple times, this leads me to believe you want all of the User.find promises resolved before you have all the results you need. For this promise.all is a good approach. Seems to me like you don't want to learn promises, if that is the case then don't bother learning JavaScript.

Comment: why code do not want to assign new values :  element.boardcards.members.push(users[i].firstName + ' ' + users[i].surname);